# A way to configure InitialSamplingPercentage in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1, appinsights

I'm setting up AppInsights on an on-premise server.

There is a setting InitialSamplingPercentage in asp.net configs for AppInsights,
Is there an analog in Aps.Net Core?

I set up my appInsights like this:

In Configure:

```
    var builder = configuration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
    builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:2);
    builder.Build();
```

And in ConfigureServices:

```
    var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
    aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
    
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way

```
    builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(new SamplingPercentageEstimatorSettings()
    {
        InitialSamplingPercentage = 0.1,
    }, (_, _, _, _, _) => { }, excludedTypes: "Exception;");
```