# Configuring Adaptive Sampling not reflected in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I am configuring Azure App Insight's adaptive sampling in my `appsettings.json` file based on this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling-classic-api#configuring-adaptive-sampling-for-aspnet-applications

My `appsettings.json`:

```json
  "ApplicationInsightsSamplingSettings": {
    "InitialSamplingPercentage": 60.0,
    "MinSamplingPercentage": 0.01,
    "MaxSamplingPercentage": 60.0,
    "MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 5
  },
```

I know that sampling is on because I can query App Insight Logs with `sum(itemCount)` and it shows a higher value than using `count()`.

```
dependencies
| summarize count() //sampled

dependencies
| summarize sum(itemCount) //Not sampled and will result in a higher number.
```

So why does the Azure Portal not reflect my sampling percentages? No matter what, the Data Sampling under App Insights >> Usage and estimated costs >> Data sampling, always return 100%.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Adaptive Sampling is enabled, it automatically sets the Sampling percentage in `Application Inisights=>Data Sampling`.

As per my observation, `InitialSamplingPercentage` doesn't reflects in the *Portal=>Application Insights=>Data Sampling* and the data sampling percentage automatically gets assigned according to the sampled data.

To configure the `InitialSamplingPercentage` manually, disable the adaptive sampling by adding the setting:

```
{
"EnableAdaptiveSampling":false
}
```

---

I have tested the same with both ASP.NET and ASP.NET core in my environment to check if the manually configured sampling percentage reflects in the Portal, but the InitialSamplingPercentage doesn't affect the Data Sampling percentage in  Portal.

`ASP.NET core:`

- Used below code to configure the settings manually in ASP.NET core. Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219249/a-way-to-configure-initialsamplingpercentage-in-asp-net-core) solution by @*Anarion*

```cs
var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    EnableAdaptiveSampling = false,
    EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = false,
};
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);

builder.Services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(telemetryConfiguration =>
{
    var telemetryProcessorChainBuilder = telemetryConfiguration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
    telemetryProcessorChainBuilder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond: 5);
    telemetryProcessorChainBuilder.UseAdaptiveSampling(new SamplingPercentageEstimatorSettings
{
     MaxSamplingPercentage=50,
     MinSamplingPercentage=0.1,
     InitialSamplingPercentage=0.1
    }, null, excludedTypes: ""); 
    telemetryProcessorChainBuilder.Build();
});
```

`ASP.NET:`

```xml
<TelemetryProcessors>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
    <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
    <InitialSamplingPercentage>0.1</InitialSamplingPercentage>
  </Add>
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
    <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
    <InitialSamplingPercentage>0.1</InitialSamplingPercentage>
  </Add>
</TelemetryProcessors>
```

- Run the below Kusto query to check the % of requests being sampled:

> union requests,dependencies,pageViews,browserTimings,exceptions,traces
> |  where  timestamp  > ago(1d)
> | summarize RetainedPercentage =  100/avg(itemCount) by bin(timestamp, 1h), itemType

[image]

As mentioned in the screenshot you have provided, if we are enabling the sampling manually using code or if the adaptive sampling enabled, it applies those settings regardless of the sampling percentage assigned in the portal.

**References:**

[Azure Application Insight Sampling Configuration | by Chhavi Goel](https://medium.com/@chhavi.goel/azure-application-insight-sampling-configuration-36bbb17c7989)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the code changes are not reflected in the portal. However, it very confusing if someone was not aware that code/configuration has changed the sampling rate. This needs fixed.